# python - How to find the largest groups with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a ratings dataframe that has rows of `userId, movieId, rating`. I want to find the user with the highest number of ratings.

**Here is the code I've written:**

```
import pandas as pd
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv') # userId,movieId,rating
user_rating_counts = ratings[['userId','movieId']].groupby('userId')['movieId'].agg(['count'])
top_rator = user_rating_counts[user_rating_counts['count']==user_rating_counts['count'].max()]
```

**Here is how the file looks like:**

```
userId,movieId,rating
1,1,4.0
1,3,4.0
1,6,4.0
1,47,5.0
1,50,5.0
1,70,3.0
1,101,5.0
1,110,4.0
```

When I view `top_rator` in jupyter notebook it looks like this:

```
       count
userId  
414     2698
```

What I want to get from it is a tuple like:

```
(414, 2698)
```

How can I do that?

P.S. any comments on how I can do this better/faster/shorter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.agg.html) with `max` and `idxmax` in list:

```
tup = tuple(ratings.groupby('userId').size().agg(['idxmax','max']))
print (tup)
(1, 8)
```

**Explanation**:

First aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) per groups:

```
#changed data - multiple groups
print (df)
   userId  movieId  rating
0       1        1     4.0
1       1        3     4.0
2       1        6     4.0
3       2       47     5.0
4       2       50     5.0
5       2       70     3.0
6       2      101     5.0
7       3      110     4.0

print (df.groupby('userId').size())
userId
1    3
2    4
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Output is `Series`, so added [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.agg.html) with list of functions `idxmax` and `max` for index and value of Series for maximum:

```
print (df.groupby('userId').size().agg(['idxmax','max']))
idxmax    2
max       4
dtype: int64
```

And last convert to `tuple`:

```
print (tuple(df.groupby('userId').size().agg(['idxmax','max'])))
(2, 4)
```

---

Solution if multiple groups with same maximum sizes:

```
print (ratings)   
   userId  movieId  rating
0       1        1     4.0
1       1        3     4.0
2       1        6     4.0
3       2       47     5.0
4       2       50     5.0
5       2       70     3.0
6       3      101     5.0
7       3      110     4.0
```

First aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) per groups, but there are 2 groups with max `3` value:

```
user_rating_counts = ratings.groupby('userId')['movieId'].size()
print (user_rating_counts)
userId
1    3
2    3
3    2
Name: movieId, dtype: int64
```

So use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first:

```
top_rator = (user_rating_counts[user_rating_counts == user_rating_counts.max()])
print (top_rator)
userId
1    3
2    3
Name: movieId, dtype: int64
```

Create `DataFrame` and convert to list of tuples:

```
tup = list(map(tuple, top_rator.reset_index().values.tolist()))
print (tup)
[(1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: can you explain to me how this does the job in one pass?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - sure, added solution also for mutiple maximum.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sizes = df.groupby(['userId']).size()
(sizes.idxmax(), sizes.max())
#(1, 8)
```

**Details**:

Groupby `userId` and get the `size` of each group.

```
sizes = df.groupby(['userId']).size()
#userId
#1    8
#2    1
```

Create the tuple of the user with the highest number of ratings using `idxmax` and `max`:

```
(sizes.idxmax(), sizes.max())
#(1, 8)
```

Comment: this is very interesting, is there any easy way to get both idxmax and max in one pass also?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - sure, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one user matching max, you can simply use:

```
next(top_rator.max(1).items())
```

#### Explanation

`top_rator.max(1)` will return:

```
userId
1    8
dtype: int64
```

[`Series.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html) lazily iterates over the Series, creating the `tuple` of index and values in a `zip` generator object.

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)is used to access the 'next' (first) `tuple` in this generator

---

If there are multiple users matching the max, use list comprehension instead:

```
[(idx, val) for idx, val in top_rator.max(1).items()]
```